# GeoGebra: LaTeX vSpace* doesnt shift up the Equation

Tags: formatting, vspace, geogebra

I want to lift the whole Equation at the end of the Code up to the left of the graphic,but Vspace* does nothing.
Does Anyone know how i could solve this?

The code is partially generated using GeoGebra.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titling}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\varname}{varcontent}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm} 
\title{Seite 09, Aufgabe 59}
\author{abcdefg}
\date{Januar 7,2024}
\maketitle

\par
\begin{enumerate}[label=]
    \item Ein Parrallelogramm ABCD,das durch die Seiten $a = 83$ und $b = 18$ und den Winkel $\alpha = 36°$. Wie lang sind die Diagonalen $e$ und $f$?
\end{enumerate}
\par\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
%transform canvas={scale=1}
    \hspace{5cm}
        
    \clip(-29.14964819200955,-19.448918907332526) rectangle (8.17579054996176,13.92168624212395);
        \draw [shift={(6.81484439144487,12.966917430607673)},line width=2.pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0,0) -- (-179.68519119261092:2.4356571180112834) arc (-179.68519119261092:-116.9248315629399:2.4356571180112834) -- cycle;
        \draw [shift={(6.81484439144487,12.966917430607673)},line width=2.pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0,0) -- (-116.9248315629399:2.4356571180112834) arc (-116.9248315629399:-89.88699071949942:2.4356571180112834) -- cycle;
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-28.404673286592075,-4.0500772114846795)-- (-1.7769063280459956,-3.9501731333510643);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-1.7769063280459956,-3.9501731333510643)-- (6.81484439144487,12.966917430607673);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-28.404673286592075,-4.0500772114846795)-- (-19.85288419835467,12.820391449345038);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-19.85288419835467,12.820391449345038)-- (6.81484439144487,12.966917430607673);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-1.7769063280459956,-3.9501731333510643)-- (6.848145750822725,-3.916871773973197);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (6.81484439144487,12.966917430607673)-- (6.848145750822725,-3.916871773973197);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-19.85288419835467,12.820391449345038)-- (-10.808234991324767,4.435109157996983);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-10.808234991324767,4.435109157996983)-- (-1.7769063280459956,-3.9501731333510643);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-28.404673286592075,-4.0500772114846795)-- (-10.808234991324767,4.435109157996983);
        \draw [line width=2.pt] (-10.808234991324767,4.435109157996983)-- (6.81484439144487,12.966917430607673);
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-28.404673286592075,-4.0500772114846795) circle (2.5pt);
            \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-27.86443687855727,-2.5211019371541186) node [left]{$A$};
            \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1.7769063280459956,-3.9501731333510643) circle (2.5pt);
            \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-1.2345857216339071,-2.4399133665537427) node [left]{$B$};
            \draw[color=black] (-14.874265582497094,-4.550816202163521) node [below] {$d$};
            \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (6.81484439144487,12.966917430607673) circle (2.5pt);
            \draw[color=rvwvcq] (7.371402762005961,14.447309318324477) node [below]{$C$};
            \draw[color=black] (3.8802942261897884,4.6234922756789745) node {$a$};
            \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-19.85288419835467,12.820391449345038) circle (2.5pt);
            \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-19.258448394917405,14.284932177123725) node [below]{$D$};
            \draw[color=black] (-22.749556930733576,4.542303705078598) node {$c$};
            \draw[color=black] (-6.349465669457602,12.336406482714699) node {$b$};
            \draw[color=black] (6.803082767803328,12.498783623915452) node [right]{$\alpha$};
            \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (6.848145750822725,-3.916871773973197) circle (2.5pt);
            \draw[color=rvwvcq] (7.452591332606337,-2.4399133665537427) node {$F$};
            \draw[color=black] (2.7436542377845226,-4.469627631563144) node {$m$};
            \draw[color=black] (5.991197061799567,5.273000840481982) node {$h_a$};
            \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-10.808234991324767,4.435109157996983) circle (2.5pt);
            \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-10.246517058275655,5.922509405284991) node {$M$};
            \draw[color=black] (-16.01090557090236,8.43935509389665) node [left]{$f$};
            \draw[color=black] (-18.852505541915523,-0.24782196034358928) node {$e$};
            \draw[color=black] (8.183288468009723,11.930463629712818) node {$\epsilon$};
        \end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \def\a{46}
    \def\b{18}
    \def\W{36} %Alpha
\begin{equation}
    \vspace*{3cm}
    \hspace{-3cm}
    \begin{split}
        e &= \sqrt{(a+m)^2+h_a^2} \\\
        \beta &= 90-\alpha \\\
        &= \the\numexpr 90-\W \relax \\\notag   
        m &= \sin{(\beta)}\cdot b \\\
        &\approx 14,56 \\\
        h_a &= \cos{(\beta)} \cdot b \\\
        &\approx 10,58 \\\
        e &= \sqrt{(a+(\sin{(\beta)}\cdot b))^2 + (\cos{(\beta)} \cdot b} \\\
        &\approx 61,48 \\\
        f &= \sqrt{(a-m)^2+h_a^2} \\\
        &= \sqrt{(a-(\sin{(\beta)}\cdot b))^2 + (\cos{(\beta)} \cdot b} \\\
        &\approx 33,17
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I Already tried using transform canvas={scale=1} to make the graph overlap, but then it lifts it up into the Title and i cant shift it down with Vspace* either.

Comment: Welcome. You have `\clip(-29.14964819200955,-19.448918907332526) rectangle (8.17579054996176,13.92168624212395);`` the figure therefore occupies all this space. Point A is at (-27.86443687855727,-2.5211019371541186). Geogebra allows you to build quickly, but I advise you to simplify the code

Comment: With `\clip[draw]` you will see

Comment: A tutorial here https://tikz.dev/tutorial

Comment: The `tkz-euclide` package might also interest you

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the fact that the code is at least partially generated with GeoGebra. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes the Graph is generated with Geogebra, this is the first code i ever partially wrote in LaTex, so it isn't that good, but thank y'all for the help, i got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoGebra produces awful Ti*k*Z code. The seemingly high precision is ridiculous, so I reduced to two decimal digits (three for the color).

Most notably, the produced code ***always*** has a ***wrong*** `\clip` instruction and a mysterious `\begin{scriptsize}` command at some point.

I suggest also to remove the humongous dots and to reduce the line width.

No `\vspace` or `\hspace` instruction is then necessary.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titling}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\varname}{varcontent}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.082,0.396,0.753}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm} 
\title{Seite 09, Aufgabe 59}
\author{abcdefg}
\date{Januar 7,2024}
\maketitle

Ein Parrallelogramm ABCD, das durch die Seiten $a = 83$ und $b = 18$ und den 
Winkel $\alpha = 36^\circ$. Wie lang sind die Diagonalen $e$ und $f$?

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
%transform canvas={scale=1}
  \draw [shift={(6.81,12.97)},line width=0.4pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.1]
    (0,0) -- (-179.69:2.43) arc (-179.69:-116.92:2.44) -- cycle;
  \draw [shift={(6.81,12.97)},line width=0.4pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.1]
    (0,0) -- (-116.92:2.43) arc (-116.92:-89.89:2.44) -- cycle;
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-28.4,-4.05) -- (-1.78,-3.95);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-1.78,-3.95) -- (6.81,12.97);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-28.4,-4.05) -- (-19.85,12.82);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-19.85,12.82)-- (6.81,12.97);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-1.78,-3.95)-- (6.85,-3.92);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (6.81,12.97)-- (6.85,-3.92);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-19.85,12.82)-- (-10.81,4.44);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-10.81,4.44)-- (-1.78,-3.95);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-28.4,-4.05)-- (-10.81,4.44);
  \draw [line width=0.4pt] (-10.81,4.44)-- (6.81,12.97);
%  \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-28.4,-4.05) circle (2.5pt);
  \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-27.86,-2.52) node [left]{$A$};
%  \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-1.78,-3.95) circle (2.5pt);
  \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-1.23,-2.44) node [left]{$B$};
  \draw[color=black] (-14.87,-4.55) node [below] {$d$};
%  \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (6.81,12.97) circle (2.5pt);
  \draw[color=rvwvcq] (7.37,14.45) node [below]{$C$};
  \draw[color=black] (3.88,4.62) node {$a$};
%  \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-19.85,12.82) circle (2.5pt);
  \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-19.26,14.28) node [below]{$D$};
  \draw[color=black] (-22.75,4.54) node {$c$};
  \draw[color=black] (-6.35,12.34) node {$b$};
  \draw[color=black] (6.8,12.5) node [right]{$\alpha$};
%  \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (6.85,-3.92) circle (2.5pt);
  \draw[color=rvwvcq] (7.45,-2.44) node {$F$};
  \draw[color=black] (2.74,-4.47) node {$m$};
  \draw[color=black] (5.99,5.27) node {$h_a$};
%  \draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-10.81,4.44) circle (2.5pt);
  \draw[color=rvwvcq] (-10.25,5.92) node {$M$};
  \draw[color=black] (-16.01,8.44) node [left]{$f$};
  \draw[color=black] (-18.85,-0.25) node {$e$};
  \draw[color=black] (8.18,11.93) node {$\epsilon$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{equation*}
%    \def\a{46}
%    \def\b{18}
    \def\W{36} %Alpha
    \begin{split}
        e &= \sqrt{(a+m)^2+h_a^2} \\
        \beta &= 90-\alpha \\
        &= \the\numexpr 90-\W \relax \\
        m &= \sin{(\beta)}\cdot b \\
        &\approx 14,56 \\\
        h_a &= \cos{(\beta)} \cdot b \\
        &\approx 10,58 \\
        e &= \sqrt{(a+(\sin{(\beta)}\cdot b))^2 + (\cos{(\beta)} \cdot b} \\
        &\approx 61,48 \\
        f &= \sqrt{(a-m)^2+h_a^2} \\
        &= \sqrt{(a-(\sin{(\beta)}\cdot b))^2 + (\cos{(\beta)} \cdot b} \\
        &\approx 33,17
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should try and better position the labels.